# PhantomJS, Selenium можно ли только часть действий визуализировать

Tags: java, selenium

Selenium я уже использовал, но мне не совсем подходит то, что я вижу все эти промежуточные страницы и тот факт, что это настолько же медленно, если бы я сам кликал по сайту. Знаю есть PhantomJS и как я понял он делает ровно то же что и селениум но без визуализации (поправьте если ошибаюсь). Мне бы не мало времени сэкономило знание о том, можно ли сделать все промежуточные запросы без визуализации и визуализировать только последнюю страницу? И всё это на java.
Еще как человеку, который первый раз попробовал селениум, расскажите о ожиданиях, о разнице с использованием Хром вебдрайвера и PhantomJS. Сам я понял, что существуют некие явные и неявные ожидания. Например должен прогрузиться javascript, каков алгоритм ожидания? Тупо пробовать не появился ли элемент в течении определенного времени?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS и selenium - совершенно разные вещи. selenium - просто инстумент.

Итак, у вас задача запускать тесты так, чтобы они вам не мешали, но при этом в конце вы могли увидеть некоторые шаги.

Если это один и тотже сайт и имеются непрерывные шаги для достижения этого шага, то нельзя. Но есть один пару вариантов решения.

1. Вы используете chromedriver и chromebrowser v57 и выше. Тепрь хром поддерживает мод `--headless`, который позволяет запускать браузер в НЕ интерактивном режиме, то есть без GUI.  вы доходите до нужного шага и запускаете еще одну версия ChromeDriver() уже без аргумента `--headless`. Таким образом дальнейшие действия можно увидеть.

   ```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   List<String> switches = new ArrayList<String>();
   switches.add("--headless");
   options.addArguments(switches);
   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
   ```
2. Если шаги непреравные и вы не можете продолжить уже в новом браузере. то можно добавить создание скриншота для каждой операции, либо запись видео. Таким образом вы сможете увидеть, что происходит.

Имеются несколько видов ожидания:

- Неявные ожидания - Implicit Waits - конфигурируют экземпляр WebDriver делать многократные попытки найти элемент (элементы) на странице в течении заданного периода времени, если элемент не найден сразу. Tолько по истечении этого времени WebDriver бросит ElementNotFoundException.

  ```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get(“http://some_url“);
  WebElement dynamicElement = 
  driver.findElement(By.id(“dynamicElement_id”));
  ```

  Неявные ожидания обычно настраиваются сразу после создания экземпляра WebDriver и действуют в течении всей жизни этого экземпляра, хотя переопределить их можно в любой момент. К этой группе ожиданий также можно отнести неявное ожидание загрузки страницы:

  ```
   driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```

  А также неявное ожидание отработки скриптов:

  ```
  driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```
- Явные ожидания - Explicit Waits - это код, который ждет наступления какого-то события, прежде чем продолжит выполнение. Такое ожидание срабатывает один раз в указанном месте.

  ```
  WebElement dynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("dynamicElement_id")));
  ```

Блоее подробно можно [почитать тут](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

P.s. теперь chromedriver работает быстрее, чем PhantomJS

Comment: Сайт один и тот же, но вот шаги прерывные или нет я определить смогу только на практике потому, что с веб я плохо знаком. Но учитывая, что каждый шаг вызывает кучу скриптов, думаю  идти придется последовательно. Минус скринов в том, что нельзя ничего удобным способом скорректировать (записи в полях).

Comment: Основная причина зачем мне это было нужно - это скорость. Но как Хромдрайвер визуализируя обходит по скорости фантом? Или имеется ввиду, что хром теперь тоже может без визуализации и он быстрее в таком режиме , чем фантом?

Comment: И если хром теперь может работать без GUI, я то думаю этим ребятам было бы не сложно реализовать возможность скрывать часть шагов. И еще вопрос. А что насчет скорости Фаерфокса?

Comment: насчет скорости Фаерфокса с чем? chromedriver и firefoxdriver быстрее, чем PhantomJS. но firefox не имеет возможности работать без гуи.

Comment: Нет, хром с GUI или фаерфокс?

Comment: И подскажите, а где прописать аргумент, чтобы без GUI хром запустить. Наверно в конце пути ?   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\MyJava\\MyApplicationWebDriver\\lib\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: Ясно.. на виндовсе надо с бубном танцевать. На люнексе  только нормально работает.

Comment: не могу про гуи сказать. вопрос обновил  для ответа как запустить с аргументами браузер